# Как правильно произносится "все равно"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

На днях наш учитель по русскому в ВУЗЕ заявил, что слово "все равно" произносится как "СЁРНО". Да, да, вы не ошиблись именно так. Помогите это я чего то не понимаю в этом мире, или у нее крыша едет 
[image: вот фото ее записи]

Comment: Он не говорил, в какой ситуации так произносится? Может быть в речи артиллеристов, выбирающих очередную цель (- пли! - куда?)? :)

Comment: Он просто заявил что так в высоких кругах говорят, мол в разговорной речи такое произношение

Comment: В высоких кругах точно нет. Там люди предпочитают говорить взвешенно и спокойно. А вот те, кто говорит быстро, или пьяные могут так сказать. Только "сёрано" (звук А короткий, невыраженный, как в английском).

Answer (score 2):

> На днях наш учитель по русскому в ВУЗЕ заявил, что слово "все равно"
>   произносится как "СЁРНО".

Наверное, **СЁРАНО**?

Из [*Русский язык и культура речи : учебное пособие для студентов нефилологических специальностей / [Гвоздева Е. В. и др.] ; Федеральное агентство по образованию, Московский гос. индустриальный ун-т, Ин-т дистанционного образования. - Москва : Изд-во МГИУ, 2008.*]:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: +1, а в быстрой разговорной речи *[а]* проглатывают. Некоторые люди действительно так говорят. А в быстрой и невнятной речи *всё равно* произносят так, что транскрипцией и не выразишь. Скажем, *[н]* и *[р]* там тоже могут не звучать, а лишь обозначаться неким намёком на звук )) (Вот только в вопросе: "Как **правильно** произносится ...")

Comment: Именно _некоторые_ люди могут так произнести это выражение; это совсем не то, что разговорное "Сан Саныч", - больше похоже на заплетающийся по какой-то "неуважительной" причине язык.

Comment: "Пчу" и "гыт" вообще странно. 0стальное нормально (звучит).